# using jquery/ajax to send/update div when link is clicked

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 2 layers that i need to update individually if a user clicks on either of them.

```
<div id=wrapper>
    <div id=upvote>
        //This div can be filled by upvote.php?id=X
        <? echo getUpVote(); ?>
        <a href=#><img src=upv.png></a>
    </div>
    <div id=downvote>
        //This div can be filled by downvote.php?id=X
        <? echo getdownVote(); ?>
        <a href=#><img src=downv.png></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the user clicks the up or down vote image, i need to fade out the contents of the div, make an ajax call to the respective php file (get request), and fade in the loaded content.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

AJAX request can be made with [$.get](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get#urldatacallbacktype) and you can fade the DIV using jQuery's animation functions like [fadeOut](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeOut#speedcallback)

Here is some code on how you might acchive what you want:

```
$( '#IdOfOneAnchor' ).click ( function () {
    var myDiv = $( '#IdOfYourDiv' );
    myDiv.fadeOut ();
    $.get (
        'url/to/your/script.php',
        {
            // put params you need here
        },
        function ( response ) {
            myDiv.html ( response ).fadeIn ();
        }
    );

    return false;
} );
```

off course you will have to change the selectors to match your DIVs/links ...

Comment: how would i do that with onclick actions?

Answer (score 0):

Attach a click handler to the anchor tags.   Find which url to use given the id of the containing div, then invoke load to replace the contents of the wrapper.  Fade out/in at the appropriate points.  Make sure that you return false from the anchor click handler to cancel the default action.

```
$('#upvote,#downvote').find('a').click( function() {
    var url  = $(this).closest('div').attr('id') + '.php?id=X';
    $('#wrapper').fadeOut();
                 .load( url, function() {
                     $('#wrapper').fadeIn();
                 });
    return false; // cancel click action
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a click handler to an element in jQuery you can do this:

```
 $("#upvote").click(clickHandler);
```

Where clickHandler is a function. Since you want to fade Out an image you can do this:

```
 $("#upimg").hide('slow');
```

will cause an element with id='upimg' to disappear slowly. You can also use fadeTo(opacity) to achieve a similar effect.

The AJAX call can be made with a call to load.

```
$('#div').load('url', {}, callback);
```

where an element with id='div' will be populated with the result of calling url, the {} is optional and callback is a function that you can include to execute after the load. The callback function may be used to fadeIn the new content.

```
 var clickHandler = function(){
    $("#upimg").hide('slow');

    $('#div').load('url', {}, callback);

 }

 var callback = function(){
    $('#div').show('slow');
 }
```